# TopAppBar button AutomationProperties styling in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to style the `AutomationProperties.Name` value with a different color? 
I get the basic text color from the dark theme in my app. I have a custom background color and thats why I need a specific `ForegroundColor` and `TextColor` for this attribute (`Value="OtherUserAppBarButton"`)

```
<Style x:Key="LogoutAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" 
              BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="OtherUserAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Other User"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE1A6;"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffffff" />
</Style>
```

Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that you will need to modify `AppBarButtonStyle` which you are basing your button style on. You can find it in `Common\StandardStyles.xaml` inside your project. You can either modify the style in this file directly or create a copy of it inside `App.xaml` if you need the unmodified style as well.

You need to change the following block inside the style's `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="TextLabel"
    Text="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"
    Margin="0,0,2,0"
    FontSize="12"
    TextAlignment="Center"
    Width="88"
    MaxHeight="32"
    TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
    Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"/>
```

As you can see the `Foreground` property is fixed to `AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush`. You can change it to `{TemplateBinding Foreground}` for it to match the color you set in `LogoutAppBarButtonStyle` or you can give it another custom fixed color directly in the template.

Also don't forget about the styles for other visual states (`PointerOver`, `Pressed`, `Disabled` and `Checked`). They are also set to theme colors. You can change them inside the `VisualStateManager` for the template